# Is hatred good for anything?

Tags: ethics

Hatred, as best as I can define it, is a hardening of the heart fuelled by anger against *perceived* enemies.  Does anything good ever come from anger and hatred?  Hatred of enemies sounds like a good idea, but as Nietzsche put it, be careful of turning into a monster yourself.

Comment: Whilst interesting, this question will attract many opinion-based answers and is therefore not a good fit for this site. I'm therefore voting to close this as _primarily opinion-based_. See the [help center](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [this meta post](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/474/2953) for more information.

Comment: @Keelan But isn't philosophy an opinion-based subject matter?

Comment: Perhaps you mean to ask if there are moral systems where hatred can be a virtue?  Or do you mean game-theoretically (and/or practically), is "hatred" an effective strategy?

Comment: See the two links I gave you.

Comment: I disagree with @Keelan, this question is a valid ethics question, even if the way the question was asked seems subjective.

Comment: @AlexanderSKing see the meta post I linked. There are many valid philosophical questions that don't fit **here**. If you think not, [edit] the question without changing the gist to show that this is fist into the SE format.

Comment: @MichaelLee I think Rex Kerr has a point - "Good" is subjective, so maybe if you could define amore clearly, eg 'for the greater good' (utility) or perhaps advantageous to the 'hater' specifically, which might be a very different thing ?

Comment: I like the question but it is really too broad and opinion based, so I voted to close. But you may want to repost your question and instead ask for views of published philosophers rather than users' opinions.

Answer (score 0):

Like all basic emotions, hatred is surely an evolutionary adaptation, so it is clearly good for something. In particular, evolutionary theory suggests that genes coding for "never hate" and genes coding for "always hate" probably tend to die out pretty quickly, while more nuanced "hate under these circumstances" genes tend to fare much better. But this is an oversimplification, of course, for example due to [pleiotropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleiotropy).

If you want a more philosophical answer, I suggest editing the question to ask "is hatred ever justified?" or some variant thereof.

Briefly, my thoughts about this modified question:

- I don't think that hating a particular ethnicity or gender is ever justified.
- Nonetheless, certain groups probably have the property that hating their members is justifiable, for example you could build a pretty convincing philosophical argument that it is morally justifiable to hate the group that we might call "emotionally cold people incapable of empathy whom get a buzz out of hurting or otherwise dominating others." Although to be honest, I think it would be exhausting to carry such strong emotions; much better to simply dislike this group, and to simply not give a darn about their well-being; after all, they don't give a darn about yours.
- It may be justifiable to hate certain ideologies, such as white supremacy, especially if those ideologies themselves promote hate or otherwise unfairly dehumanise certain groups of people. On the other hand, it could be argued that it makes more sense to carefully and thoughtfully argue against ideologies that promote hate, rather than to hate those ideologies ourselves. Once again, let me just point out that hating an ideology sounds pretty exhausting, and that there are much better ways to work for change in the world.

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a network for exchanging opinions, but rather factual information. This answer essentially isn't more than stating your opinion. Please improve this question by providing references to philosophers supporting your theory (or delete your answer). For more information, see [this meta post](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/474/2953).

Comment: @Keelan, unfortunately, I find your comment distinctly anti-philosophical. Philosophy should be, and largely is, based on the idea that we should justify our opinions not with appeals to authority, but with arguments. Yet you seem to be saying that if I provide references to philosophers supporting my opinions, then this would improve my answer. Nonsense; appeals to authority belong here sparingly, if at all. If anything, the answer would be improved by laying bare the assumptions and thought process that lead to these opinions, and then taking *those* assumptions...

Comment: ... treating them as opinions, and deconstructing them. Wash, rinse, and repeat. In any event, no matter how far you go with this process, you will always find more assumptions, i.e. opinions. Now you may retort: "But you're missing the point; we're not here to philosophize, we're here to learn *about* philosophy." To which I would retort; no, *you're* missing the point; learning about philosophy without philosophizing is exactly what we shouldn't be doing; this is just putting our faith in authority, which is the antithesis of what this should be all about.

Comment: In any event, every sincere answer that makes specific claims is fundamentally factual, the fact being: "This is what I believe." Including references of the form "This is what someone else believes" doesn't make it any more factual.

Comment: Did you even read the post I linked? This platform is **not** for exchanging *your* opinions. It's about exchanging the ideas of philosophical doctrines and related things.

Comment: @Keelan, did you even read the comments that I posted? This platform should **not** distinguish opinions by whose opinions they are, since this is not the relevant factor; furthermore, philosophical doctrines **are** opinions. And yes, I read the post you linked.

Comment: Yes, except that it *is* relevant, as explained in the post I linked.

Comment: I have thought this based on other posts/comments in the past: If citing existing philosopher's works is the only way to make an answer more valid, then this SE becomes an index for all that's already written of philosophy, and seemingly does not allow for any new thinking.

Comment: @user2808054 also this is explained in the post I linked. **We don't do philosophy here.** We *discuss* philosophy. Can you imagine writing a paper and adding as footnote reference 'goblin user on Philosophy.SE'? Sure, the ideas may be interesting and to the point, but this is not the place to ventilate them.

Comment: @Keelan the post is long, so I haven't read the whole thing, but I have skimmed it. Also you don't state with what authority you are all over this question, telling everyone how to answer it (or not). You'd do well to explain that.

Comment: @user2808054 the post I linked to was written by a moderator, I'm really only restating what he said there. Perhaps you should read the whole thing. Also note that that post has +12/-0, so it seems to be the opinion of the community here.

Comment: @Keelan, perhaps the +12 votes merely indicate agreement with the sentiment that "We are here to learn -- not to vent, bully or distract," as opposed to indicating agreement with the sentiment "we should not do philosophy here." Really, someone should try to write an objective, unbiased meta question to find out what users *real* feelings are about this issue. If it really does turn out that the vast majority of users want no philosophy to be done here, then I will delete my answer.

Comment: Upvotes typically indicate agreement with the main points of the post. If you don't think that question has been discussed enough in the post I linked before or [here](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/1544/2953), [here](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/2794/2953), [here](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/2767/2953), [here](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/1754/2953), [here](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/1751/2953) or [here](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/1749/2953)... ask a new question yourself.

Comment: And don't forget the help center: [What can I ask about](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) - [How do I ask a good question?](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) - [How do I write a good answer?](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) - [How to reference material written by others?](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) - all support my statement in one way or the other.